# jQuery: dynamically appened elements + .on()

Tags: jquery, dom, href

I have a series of HREFs with the class *buy*. I override these when clicked as follows:

```
$('.buy').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var me = $(this);
     // other stuff here...
```

This works fine as expected. Problem comes when I attach more of these links to the DOM dynamically. When clicking on these links, they are not captured. I thought that binding using the *.on()* method would work with items not present in the DOM when the JS loaded.

Not sure why and I cannot seem to figure it out. Using the standard click capture with *.on* doesn't work, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.buy', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var me = $(this);
     // other stuff here...
});
```

The event needs to be delegated to a static element, the 2nd argument is the selector you wish the function to run against.

Your way, while still maintaining on, doesn't attach it to a static element that's bound to page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.target` function too:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buy', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var me = $(e.target);
   alert(me.attr('id'));
});
```

this one not tested but might work:

```
$('.buy').on('click',function(e){     
   e.preventDefault();
   var me = $(e.target);
   alert(me.attr('id'));
});
```